# How To show ol-3 Layer Switcher

Tags: php, google-maps, gis, mapbox, openlayers-3

I'm developing a GIS and I have trouble to show Layer Switcher. In this case I used Open Layers 3.

```
map = new ol.Map({
        controls: ol.control.defaults({
          attribution: false
        }).extend([mousePositionControl,zoomslider]),
        target: document.getElementById('map'),
        layers: [
    new ol.layer.Group({
        'title': 'BaseMaps',
        layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            title: 'RoadMaps',
            source: new ol.source.OSM({
                url: 'http://mt{0-3}.google.com/vt/lyrs=m&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}',
                attributions: [
                new ol.Attribution({ html: '© Google' }),
                new ol.Attribution({ html: '<a href="https://developers.google.com/maps/terms">Terms of Use.</a>' })
                ]
            })
        }),
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            title: 'Satelite',
            type: 'base',
            visible: false,
            source: new ol.source.OSM({
                url: 'http://mt{0-3}.google.com/vt/lyrs=m&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}',
                attributions: [
                new ol.Attribution({ html: '© Google' }),
                new ol.Attribution({ html: '<a href="https://developers.google.com/maps/terms">Terms of Use.</a>' })
                ]
            })
        }),
            new ol.layer.Tile({
            title: 'OSM',
            type: 'base',
            visible: true,
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
        })
        ]
        peta_highlight,
        layers['layer_kategori'],
    })
        ],

        view: new ol.View({
            projection: "EPSG:3857",
        })              
    });

    layerSwitcher = new ol.control.LayerSwitcher({
    tipLabel: 'Légende' // Optional label for button
    });
    map.addControl(layerSwitcher);
```

At this point my code is still not working and the three maps can't show on my website.

Comment: check the sample code here on how to show layer switcher in open layers : https://github.com/walkermatt/ol3-layerswitcher

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have included the layer switcher library properly it's not the layer switcher that's causing the trouble but a bunch of errors in how you are defining the map.

There's a comma missing before `peta_higlight` and `layers['layer_kategori'],` doesn't make any sense.

[`ol.View`](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.View.html) requires you to add a center and resolution/zoom.

The following code should fix those for you

```
map = new ol.Map({
    controls: ol.control.defaults({
        attribution: false
    }).extend([new ol.control.MousePosition, new ol.control.ZoomSlider]),
    target: document.getElementById("map"),
    layers: [new ol.layer.Group({
        title: "BaseMaps",
        layers: [
            new ol.layer.Tile({
                title: "RoadMaps",
                source: new ol.source.OSM({
                    url: "http://mt{0-3}.google.com/vt/lyrs=m&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}",
                    attributions: [new ol.Attribution({
                        html: "© Google"
                    }), new ol.Attribution({
                        html: '<a href="https://developers.google.com/maps/terms">Terms of Use.</a>'
                    })]
                })
            }),
            new ol.layer.Tile({
                title: "Satelite",
                type: "base",
                visible: false,
                source: new ol.source.OSM({
                    url: "http://mt{0-3}.google.com/vt/lyrs=m&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}",
                    attributions: [new ol.Attribution({
                        html: "© Google"
                    }), new ol.Attribution({
                        html: '<a href="https://developers.google.com/maps/terms">Terms of Use.</a>'
                    })]
                })
            }),
            new ol.layer.Tile({
                title: "OSM",
                type: "base",
                visible: true,
                source: new ol.source.OSM()
            }), peta_highlight
        ]
    })],
    view: new ol.View({
        center: [0, 0],
        zoom: 5,
        projection: 'EPSG:3857'
    })
});

layerSwitcher = new ol.control.LayerSwitcher({
    tipLabel: 'Légende' // Optional label for button
});
map.addControl(layerSwitcher);
```